# Assigning variables according to dynamic queries

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a function on my local server in order to calculate a certain value, whose variables are stored on different tables

```
SET @tmquery = CONCAT("SELECT SUM(x) FROM table", year, " WHERE id = ", id);

PREPARE stmt FROM @tmquery;
SET tm = (EXECUTE stmt);
```

I need the year and id values (which are received as parameters) in order to filter the information so I can get the SUM() of relevant data, but I also need to save that SUM() value on a different variable in order to use it afterwards, what can I do in order to accomplish this?

Comment: I think your `CONCAT()` is missing a whitespace before `WHERE`, unless `year` ends with a whitespace character.

Comment: Thanks for the observation @still_learning , I edited the question, however the problems seems to be on the `SET tm = (EXECUTE stmt);` line